# Homotopical generalizations of the isotopy extension theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

It's a well known theorem that given isotopic embeddings $i_1,i_2: M \rightarrow S^d$, there is a homeomorphism $\phi:S^d \rightarrow S^d$ which restricts to homeomorphisms $\operatorname{im}(i_1) \cong \operatorname{im}(i_2)$ and $S^d -\operatorname{im}(i_1) \cong S^d -\operatorname{im}(i_2)$. I am interested in a homotopical generalization of this fact.

Suppose $f:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ is a homotopy equivalence such that the mapping cylinder $\operatorname{Cyl}(f)$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it the case there is a homotopy equivalence $S^d \rightarrow S^d$, restricting to $M_1 \xrightarrow{f} M_2$ and to a homotopy equivalence of $S^d - \operatorname{im}(f|_{M_1}) \simeq S^d - \operatorname{im}(f|_{M_2}) $?

Through mostly elementary means, I was able to produce a map $S^d \rightarrow S^d$ which restricts to an equivalence $(\operatorname{Tub}(M_1),\partial \operatorname{Tub}(M_1)) \rightarrow (\operatorname{Tub}(M_2),\partial \operatorname{Tub}(M_2))$, but I do not know how to ensure that complements are preserved. I am also willing to assume $d$ is arbitrarily high.